# MySQL: decrypt password

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption

```
INSERT INTO users_tbl (`fName`, `lName`, `email`, `password`) 
VALUES ('Nick', 'Furry', 'nick@example.com', PASSWORD('nick333'));
```

I used `PASSWORD()` function provided by MySQL to encrypt the password and the password column is encrypted, but now I do not know how to decrypt it. I didn't use those hash methods. Can anyone tell me how to decrypt it?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PASSWORD function performs encryption one-way so basically, there is no way to decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @phnkha stated, this is a one way encryption, but this is actually a good thing - you shouldn't store passwords in a way that allows to decrypt them in the future. The correct way to do it is to store it encrypted and use the same encryption algorithm when the user is trying to authenticate and compare the encrypted values.
2. You shouldn't use the PASSWORD function, it's used internally. You should use MD5 or SHA1 (assuming you're using MySQL).

Comment: MD5 and SHA1 are not suitable for password hashing (it doesn't get much worse, actually). Use a [function designed specifically for hashing passwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Key_derivation_functions), such as argon2, bcrypt, scrypt, PBKDF2.